# Dynamically adding form fields to reactive forms in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-reactive-forms, dynamic-forms

I'm having some trouble getting form fields to populate from an array. My original thinking is to input the array from individual components to a single component that will handle the form. Instead of making multiple forms. But I can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated! I've been through Google/stack/medium and can't seem to find anything. I've done an example on plunkr.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t7hcq6

In the ts file:

```js
  public demoForm: FormGroup;
  public arrayItems: data = [];

  private formFields = ["Sku", "Title"];

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.demoForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      demoArray: this._formBuilder.array([])
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formFields.map(field => {
      this.arrayItems.push({ title: field });
      this.demoArray.push(this._formBuilder.control(''));
    });
  }

  get demoArray() {
    return this.demoForm.get("demoArray") as FormArray;
  }
```

In the template:

```html
<form [formGroup]="demoForm">
   <div formArrayName="demoArray" 
      *ngFor="let arrayItem of arrayItems; let i=index">
      <input type="checkbox"[formControl]="demoArray[i]">
      <label>{{arrayItem.title}}</label>
   </div>
</form>
```

Thank you guys.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to provide some code here on your question to help us answer. Are you using `FormArray`?

Comment: Sorry @WillAlexander This is my first time contributing to Stack I wasn't aware. The problem has now been resolved however below. Thanks for taking the time though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your template like so:

```html
<form [formGroup]="demoForm">
   <div formArrayName="demoArray" 
      *ngFor="let arrayItem of arrayItems; let i=index">
      <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i"> <!-- this line -->
      <label>{{arrayItem.title}}</label>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help on this. I appreciate your support!

Comment: How to add a new checkbox using this example?

Comment: @RafaelGuimarães `this.demoArray.push(this._formBuilder.control(/* your new control stuff */));`